# Regex: match pattern in all words of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern that matches leading characters before (a, b, c or i) in **only** the **first** word of a string: `/^\s*[^abci]+(?=\w)/i`  such that:

```
"sanity".replace(/^\s*[^abi]+(?=\w)/i, (pattern) => 'v');
  // "vanity"
```

How do i define the regex `newRegex` such that it matches leading characters in every word of a string so that:

```
 "sanity is a rice".replace(newRegex, (pattern) => 'v');
```

outputs:    vanity is a vice

Comment: Try [`.replace(/\b[^\Wabi]/gi, 'v')`](https://regex101.com/r/TVjRVD/1)

Comment: `/.../g` = global flag to ensure all possible matches, not just the first one

Comment: Another similar: [`/\b[^abi]\B/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/1Fz2mJ/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you want to replace any word char other than `a`, `b`, `i` at the beginning of a word.

You may use

```
.replace(/\b[^\Wabi]/gi, 'v')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TVjRVD/1).

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^\Wabi]` - a negated character class that matches any char other than a non-word char (so, all word chars are matched except the chars that are also present in this class), `a`, `b` and `i`.

The global modifier `g` is added so as to match all occurrences.

JS demo:

```js
console.log(
     "sanity is a rice".replace(/\b[^\Wabi]/gi, 'v')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using `split()` and `map()` to remove the first char and get the desired output:

```js
function replaceChar(str){
  var matchChar = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'i'];
  var changedArr = str.split(/\s+/).map((item) => {
    if(matchChar.includes(item.charAt(1))){
      return 'v' + item.substr(1, item.length);
    }
    return item;
  });
  return changedArr.join(' ');
}
var str = 'sanity is a rice';
console.log(replaceChar(str));
str = 'This is a mice';
console.log(replaceChar(str));
```

Comment: Question is "replace with regEx", why are you not making use of that ?.

Comment: @AkhilAravind you should read what i said `You can also try` ? Notice that `also` there? This is a suggested answer.